# Get User Location With Http host Not Working

Tags: angular, ssl, iis, https, location

I want to Get Use Location In Angular App With Browser

```
 if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
          model.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
          model.longitude = position.coords.longitude;

      } else {
        this.message = "Browser Not Support";
      }
```

and Correctly can User Location 
But  when Publish my website on IIS Get Error

> [Deprecation] getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work
>   on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider
>   switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See

After Search on Google I found Most Website Host On HTTPS

So I Have Some Question

1 - Is There Any Other Way For Get Location Without Use HTML5 Command ?

2 - My Website Host On Local IIS with Ip `192.168.10.5:1111` And Users On My Local Area Network Access To website And Another Users Outside Of Network First Connect to VPN And Then Connect to Website

Now I Want Use HTML5 Command For Get Location Most My Website Host On HTTPS

I tried all the possible ways

I tried all the tutorials on Google

I Test All Of Google Search 'SSL LocalHost IIS' and 'self signed ssl certificate'
But When Open Url `https://192.168.10.5:443` My Website Not Secure Erro With Chrome

And At The End I Want To know Which Can Connect to Local Https Website From Vpn ?

And Can Create Free SSL On LocalHost and Do not Need Buy The SSL ?

I apologize if it gets longer

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you can get a free SSL/TLS certificate from `letsencrypt` (just google it) and then apply it to your IIS Server. But probably StackOverflow is not the best place to ask this question. It's better to ask in the [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) site since it's a server and not coding problem.